# Items are stored between body tags instead of between head tags

Tags: php, html

When I upload project files to ftp, Items moving to between body tags which are stored between head tags. When I test it in my localhost, it's fine and there is no problem about it.

header.php file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>MEYDANOKU</title>
<link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
//contents here
```

and there is footer.php file and it has end of the body and html tags.

footer.php file

```
<div id="footer1">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What is wrong with these files ? In localhost it seems perfect but when I upload to ftp, head contents moving between body tags.

site address :

> http://www.meydanoku.org

Comment: I cant see head content between the body tags when I view source

Comment: I can't find your problem on the linked website

Comment: I don't see an issue either. What browser, version and OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 8 and Mozilla Firefox but try to check it with FireBug. Head is empty when I try to edit it with FireBug.

Answer (score 2):

You have a single space before your opening doctype tag:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
```

delete this space:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

This will fix it.

The content of head tag is not actually being placed into the body, it is just a browser (probably Google Chrome right?) bug when there is content before opening doctype tag.

Click 'view source' instead of 'inspect element' to see the actual source, rather than the browsers generated DOM

Comment: Try to check it with FireBug. Head is empty when I try to edit it with FireBug

Comment: @OwnurD Yes, because firebug views the generated DOM, like i said. View source will show you the actual html. Did you try to remove the space as i said?

Comment: There is no space in header.php file Im lookin for that

Comment: @OwnurD that space is comming from somewhere, maybe the file that includes header.php outputs it. Track down that space.

Comment: Can you check it again, I just changed editor coding from UTF-8 to UTF-8 Without BOM. There is still space.

Comment: @OwnurD as all i can see is the output html, i cant see any difference. Somewhere in your code a space is being output before that tag. If there is no space in header.php then it must be in another file, probably the one that includes header.php. The space could be at the very beginning of a file, before the opening php tag

Answer (score 0):

There is a space before `<!DOCTYPE html>` on the site. But I don't see that anything is inside body instead of head

Comment: Try to check it with FireBug. Head is empty when I try to edit it with FireBug

Comment: This will fix it, just remove that space